# Non-host USB serial terminal

Tags: android, windows, usb, samsung-mobile, usbserial

Does anyone know a serial terminal emulator working on samsung galaxy s3 that acts as an USB device instead of USB host? Or such windows terminal emulator? The idea is to test a USB/RS232 bridge implemented on a uC board acting as an USB host.

Comment: Android devices typically only implement a few USB device modes - mass storage or MTP, ADB if enabled, something for tethering, and ADK. You'd probably need to change the kernel to do something else.  You might find that easier with a dev board than a consumer device.

Comment: There are some USB serial terminals, but often for (specific) adapter cables, or require OTG.

Comment: The "test" idea is a little odd - that suggests there's already a protocol scheme developed.  In which case it's likely going to be easier to modify the intended connected device or a random USB microcontroller into a tester than an secured android device.  But an android device running a custom kernel, or better yet an embedded linux development board with a USB device or OTG port would be an option.  Try to pick one which also has a serial or network port you can use for debug console/terminal access while hacking on the USB.  If you are starting from scratch, try ADK or pre-security ADB.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not in my hands. The board is supposed to act as an USB-serial plus an additional protocol layer on top of the serial (handled by the board), and it should use a some Android program as an UI. The Android USB driver modification is out of the question. I'd just like to be able to see if the basig USB-serial communication works - either with Android or Windows, but it's hard to get windows machine to act as an USB CDC device.

Comment: If android is the host, you should be able to do this with existing apis.  But if android is the device, then you must either **modify** its usb driver, **change your mind** on the protocol to one its driver supports, or **cancel** the project.